# Spacing Error with mdframed Over Page Break

Tags: margins, page-breaking, mdframed

I'm having a bit of trouble with the `mdframed` environment. I'm using it to enclose Examples in my text in a light gray background box (and control spacing around the text). When the frame splits over a page, it leaves less padding between the top of the box on the next page and the first line of text on the new page; I'd like to increase that amount of space. See the screenshot below.

Is there any way to do this? If an alternative setup is needed, I'm open to such solutions.

My `example` environment is declared thusly:

```
\usepackage{mdframed}
\newenvironment{example}[1]
{\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=vlightgray,linecolor=vlightgray,innerleftmargin=1em,innerrightmargin=1em,innertopmargin=1em,innerbottommargin=1em,skipabove=1em]
    \textbf{Example \arabic{chapter}.\arabic{exampleNum}} #1

    \vspace{1em}
    \noindent \ignorespaces}%
{\end{mdframed} \vspace{0.25em}}
```

[image]

Here is a MWE; the spacing problem is demonstrated at the top of the second page.

```
\documentclass[12pt,openright,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{vlightgray}{gray}{0.925}

\newcounter{exampleNum}
\setcounter{exampleNum}{1}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\newenvironment{example}[1]
{\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=vlightgray,linecolor=vlightgray,innerleftmargin=1em,innerrightmargin=1em,innertopmargin=1em,innerbottommargin=1em,skipabove=1em]
        \textbf{Example \arabic{chapter}-\arabic{exampleNum}} \normalsize #1

        \vspace{1em}
        \stepcounter{exampleNum}
        \noindent \ignorespaces}%
    {\end{mdframed} \vspace{0.25em}}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-3]

    \begin{example}{Consider this the prompt for the problem. Find $a$.}
        \lipsum[1-2]
    \end{example}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you post a small compilable code demonstrating the problem?

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: @Bernard A MWE has been added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tool for this is the parameter `splittopskip`, which defaults to 0pt (§ 6.9, p.9 of the documentation):

```
\documentclass[12pt, openright,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{vlightgray}{gray}{0.925}

\newcounter{exampleNum}
\setcounter{exampleNum}{1}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\newenvironment{example}[1]
{\begin{mdframed}[backgroundcolor=vlightgray,linecolor=vlightgray,innerleftmargin=1em,innerrightmargin=1em,innertopmargin=1em,innerbottommargin=1em,skipabove=1em, splittopskip=\baselineskip]
        \textbf{Example \arabic{chapter}-\arabic{exampleNum}} \normalsize #1

        \vspace{1em}
        \stepcounter{exampleNum}
        \noindent \ignorespaces}%
    {\end{mdframed} \vspace{0.25em}}

\begin{document}

    \lipsum[1-3]

    \begin{example}{Consider this the prompt for the problem. Find $a$.}
        \lipsum[1-2]
    \end{example}

\end{document}
```

[image]